# Certificate has expired [CERT_HAS_EXPIRED]

Tags: ironworker

When sending via Iron Worker, I have below problem as:

```
{ [FetchError: request to https://xxxx/api/send-mail failed, reason: certificate has expired]
  message: 'request to https://xxxx/api/send-mail failed, reason: certificate has expired',
  type: 'system',
  errno: 'CERT_HAS_EXPIRED',
  code: 'CERT_HAS_EXPIRED' }
```

NOTE: I check and see that our certificate still works well.

Please help me review this problem.

Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is not IronWorker related issue. This is the issue with your code or environment your code is running in. For example, the docker image can be deprecated. If you run your code locally in the same docker container - you will get the same error.

One of the possible solutions is to disable SSL validation on client side. In node application you can do it by setting the following env variable:

```
NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0'
```

IronWorker allows to pass env variables in "iron register" command using "-e" flag:

```
iron registed -e NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0' YOUR_DOCKER_IMAGE:TAG
```